# Show that $f$:(x when rational, 0 when irrational) is only continuous at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

Let $f$ be the function defined by:

\begin{cases} 
      x & x\in \mathbb{Q}  \\
      0 & x\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q} 
   \end{cases}
We want to show that $f$ is only continuous at $x=0$ and nowhere else.

---

The way I went about showing this was by breaking up my argument into two cases;

1. Showing continuity at 0
2. Showing the lack of continuity on $\mathbb{R}\backslash$$\{0\}$

For the first part, I began with a little rough work to find what function of $\epsilon$ I would let $\delta$ be. So formally,

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta  = \epsilon$, so that $\forall$ $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where $|x-0|<\delta$, we get $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$. To show this, we employ the fact that both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus we know that we can find a value of $x$ in the neighbourhood $(-\delta,\delta)$ which is either $\in\mathbb{Q}$ or $\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$.

In the case $x\in\mathbb{Q}$:
\begin{align}
|f(x)-0|\
=|x-0|=|x|<\delta=\epsilon
\end{align}

Similarly, if $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$:
\begin{align}
|f(x)-0| = |0-0|=0<\epsilon
\end{align}

$\therefore$ $f$ is continuous at 0.

---

The second part is where I struggled a little more to formalize my proof. My goal was to use contradiction, motivated by the similarity of this function to the Dirichlet function. So,

Suppose for contraction that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$. Let $\epsilon = |x|$ (is this even allowed?) where $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$. And then the plan was to go into the two cases of my arbitrary $a\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ being either irrational or rational to find a contraction in the definition s.t. $|f(x)-f{a)| < \epsilon$.

Again using the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we can find an $x$ in the neighbourhood $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ where $x\in\mathbb{Q}$. Starting with $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, this yields,

\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(a)|=|x-0|=|x|<\epsilon=|x| \rightarrow\leftarrow
\end{align}

But now I'm not sure how I'll continue this when $a\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$.

If anyone has any hints or clues on how to proceed or if there are glaring errors present in my work thus far, pointing them out would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\Bbb R \setminus \{\Bbb Q\} = \Bbb R$. You probably meant $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$

Comment: Hint : The irrational numbers form a dense set in $\mathbb R$. Use this to show that every neighbourhood around any point contains a root of this function. This immediately gives one of the directions of the proof.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes! will fix!

Comment: "Suppose for contraction": I think the word is contradiction, not contraction.

Comment: We may assume "contraction" is a "contraction" of "contradiction" , @Tzimmo , just joking !

Comment: @Prem Thanks for the joke, it actually made me laugh.